# BufferedReader can't be declared opening a file without entering a catch-22

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to declare a BufferedReader in order to read information from a .txt file. I declare it in the following way:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("input-file.txt"))));
```

Now, I have a small problem with this, because Java complains if I don't declare it in a try/catch block - after all, there's no guarantee the system will find input-file, so I need to catch any IOException thrown. But if I put that declaration in a try-catch block, then Java ALSO complains; I reference br later using the .readLine() method, and since br is declared in a try/catch block, there's no guarantee that BufferedReader will be created. But if I try to take BufferedReader out of the try/catch block to be sure it's created, then I can't catch the IOException...how do I escape this trap?

Comment: I don't understand the catch-22 you're talking about; I've created readers-of-streams before without issue. Can you post the exact code that you feel would create a catch-22, or as close to it as possible? Otherwise we're left guessing as to what your actual problem is.

Comment: Agree with @yshavit... without seeing the code, it's not clear what the exact problem is.  Also, don't say "Java complains".  Java doesn't complain; it gives you specific information about what the error is, which you need to share with us.

Answer (score 3):

You could read from BufferedReader inside try-catch block:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("input-file.txt"))))) {
    String s = br.readLine();
} catch (IOException io) {}
```

Comment: He said in his question that he already tried it in a try-catch block

Comment: He tried to only declare BufferedReader instance, not use it

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with I/O resources `java compiler` force you to process unexpected errors which might happen before hand. That is called `checked exception` in Java and there is no way to avoid it. So, if you want to read a file, you can do it as follow:

```
new FileReader("input-file.txt");
```

If there is no such file it throws `FileNotFoundException` and this is `checked exception` and compiler force you to process it at compile time. You can decorate it within `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input-file.txt"));
```

`BufferedReader` implements `AutoCloseable` interface and you can declare it within `try` in `try-with-resources` statement as follow:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input-file.txt"))) { ... }
```

Compiler will force you to handle `FileNotFoundException` and also `IOException`. When `try` block completes its execution it calls `close` method automatically and that method may throw this `IOException`, so this is the reason why you should handle it too. So, the complete version might look as follow:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input-file.txt"))) {
    // your logic

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```